# Fetch all pages using python request

Tags: python, pagination, python-requests

I am using an api to fetch orders from a website. The problem is at one time it only fetch only 20 orders. I figured out i need to use a pagination iterator but dont know to use it. How to fetch all the orders all at once.

My code:

```
def search_orders(self):
    headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer %s' % self.token,'Content-Type':'application/json',}
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search"
    filter = {"filter": {"states": ["APPROVED","PACKED"],},}
    return requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(filter), headers=headers)
```

Here is a link to documentation.

[Documentation](https://seller.flipkart.com/api-docs/order-api-docs/OMAPIRef.html#post-orders-search)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to do what the documentation suggests -

> The first call to the Search API returns a finite number of results based on the pageSize value. **Calling the URL returned in the nextPageURL field of the response gets the subsequent pages of the search result.**
>
> **nextPageUrl** - String - A GET call on this URL fetches the next page results. Not present for the last page

(Emphasis mine)

You can use `response.json()` to get the json of the response. Then you can check the flag - `hasMore` - to see if there are more if so, use `requests.get()` to get the response for next page, and keep doing this till `hasMore` is false. Example -

```
def search_orders(self):
    headers = {'Authorization':'Bearer %s' % self.token,'Content-Type':'application/json',}
    url = "https://api.flipkart.net/sellers/orders/search"
    filter = {"filter": {"states": ["APPROVED","PACKED"],},}
    s = requests.Session()
    response = s.post(url, data=json.dumps(filter), headers=headers)
    orderList = []
    resp_json = response.json()
    orderList.append(resp_json["orderItems"])
    while resp_json.get('hasMore') == True:
        response = s.get('"https://api.flipkart.net/sellers{0}'.format(resp_json['nextPageUrl']))
        resp_json = response.json()
        orderList.append(resp_json["orderItems"])
    return orderList
```

The above code should return the complete list of orders.

Comment: "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL            Giving this Error

Comment: Oh ok sorry, Could not test this as did not have the required info to make the post call. Updated it in my answer.

Comment: raise InvalidURL("Invalid URL %r: No host supplied" % url)

Comment: try printing `resp_json.get('hasMore')` and `resp_json['nextPageUrl']` , what does it give?

Comment: also try the latest code i have given, `resp_json.get('hasMore')` might be returning a string.

Comment: True
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

Comment: hasMore and nextPageUrl. Next Page Url has been cut off due to long size

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/85490/discussion-between-anand-s-kumar-and-manish-gupta).